# Applying a function to a list with fixed intervals and fill the resulting list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to apply a function `f` to a list with fixed intervals, and then fill the gaps of the resulting list, as shown in the following picture. Since it will be run many times, it needs to be fast. The list has coordinates as its elements, which means for example `a = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}`.
[image]

The motivation for this question is this. Because applying the function f to many elements is time-consuming, so I apply f to a smaller subset of the list. The subset is considered to be an approximation of the full list. To achieve this, the elements can be thought of having an influence range. For this case, an element can influnce its left and right neighbors. If the resulting list does not have the same length with the original list, it should be filled to match with the original list.

Comment: how should it fill the gaps if the sequence is `f /@ {1,3,5,7...}`?

Comment: And what if the length of the list in your example is `9` ... you should add `f@10`, but the `10` isn't there and also you haven't specified that the list elements are integers, so one could suspect that the problem is underspecified

Comment: Underspecified, as noted, and what have you tried? In general, "I want this, do it for me...." questions are frowned upon.

Comment: In the edited example you're not using equal intervals. Voting to close as unclear. Please take your time to answer my questions above.

Comment: @ belisarius, I present a short list for demonstration. The interval is 3, because each element has 2 neighbors. The interval seems unequal at first sight in this specific example, because the resulting list has to match with the original list in length. So I have to apply 'f' to the last element. I was thinking someone had encountered the same problem with me. I think it could be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's my guess at interpreting ambiguity:

```
func=With[{l = #, ll = #2, f = #3},
  Join[ConstantArray[f@#[[1]], Ceiling[ll/2]],
      Flatten[ConstantArray[f@#, ll] & /@ Rest@#, 1]][[;; 
       Length@l]] &@Append[l[[;; ;; ll]], l[[-1]]]] &;

func[Range@10,3,k]

(* {k[1], k[1], k[4], k[4], k[4], k[7], k[7], k[7], k[10], k[10]} *)
```

On your new example:

```
func[[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 3, f]

(* {f[a], f[a], f[d], f[d], f[d], f[g], f[g], f[g], f[i]} *)
```

Or spitting some random 3-tuples into the list values:

```
Block[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i},
 {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i} = RandomInteger[10, {9, 3}];
 Column[{{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 
   func[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 3, k]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `@ciao, it seems the question is not stated clearly. I added some explanation to my question.

Comment: @novice: Well, output matches your new example (obviously, use some other name for the function than *f* if *f* is part of the target, or just apply the function directly), so give it a whirl and report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = Range[8];
n = 3;

sel = Take[list, {1, -1, n}]
base = f /@ sel
filled = ConstantArray[base, n] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}
Take[filled, -Length@list]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 7}
>
> {f[1], f[4], f[7]}
>
> {f[1], f[1], f[1], f[4], f[4], f[4], f[7], f[7], f[7]}
>
> {f[1], f[1], f[4], f[4], f[4], f[7], f[7], f[7]}
> ```

Comment: I don't understand the filling criteria.Take for example `list = Range[9];
n = 7;` Why did you decide to include only two ones in the result?

Comment: @belisarius Without further specification this appeared as correct as any.  Hopefully the OP can figure out what to replace the last line with if something else is needed.

Comment: Not very important, but you may want to check the last part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is underspecified. The following is a possible solution. I wanted to use `Downsample`, motivation is just mine.

```
meanField[list_List, downSample_Integer, fun_] :=
 Module[{ds, nst, r = Range@Length@list},
  ds = Downsample[r, downSample];
  nst = Nearest[Thread[ds -> fun /@ list[[ds]]]];
  Flatten[nst[#, 1] & /@ r, 1]
  ]

list = CharacterRange["a", "j"];
meanField[list, 2, r]
(* {r["a"], r["a"], r["c"], r["c"], r["e"], r["e"], r["g"], r["g"], r["i"], r["i"]}*)

meanField[list, 3, r]
(*{r["a"], r["a"], r["d"], r["d"], r["d"], r["g"], r["g"], r["g"],  r["j"], r["j"]}*)

MatrixPlot[Table[meanField[Range@9, i, Identity], {i, 9}], ColorFunction-> "CMYKColors",
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   MapThread[Downsample,{Table[Disk[{n,9 - m}, .1], {m,.5,9,1}, {n,.5,9,1}], Range@9}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare for example with Mr.Wizard's to understand why your problem is poorly defined:

```
mr[list_, n_, f_] := Module[{sel, base, filled},
  sel = Take[list, {1, -1, n}];
  base = f /@ sel;
  filled = ConstantArray[base, n]~Flatten~{2, 1};
  Take[filled, -Length@list]
  ]
MatrixPlot[mr[Range@9, #, Identity] & /@ Range@9, ColorFunction -> "CMYKColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: On a second thought, I don't know if it _really_ matters

Comment: @  belisarius, In fact the function f does not matter, I only need to find a subset of a list to approximate the list uniformly(i.e. fixed interval), on the condition that the approximation list has the equal size.  It is like using {{5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5}} to approximate {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}. In Chebyshev metric, the elements are 1 element neighbor of 5.

Comment: @novice Sorry, I am not able to understand your comment. Of course  `f` doesn't matter. Have I said on the contrary?

Comment: @ belisarius, not a good example. It should like this: using {{5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5}} to approximate {{4.6, 4.7, 4.8}, {4.9, 5, 5.1}, {5.2, 5.3, 5.4}}. Something like using the average value to smooth the list, or the first pic shown here : http://philipbjorge.com/2011/12/02/2d-multigrid-red-black-sor-in-ada95-part-2/